# Algebra Trick Question

Tags: linear-algebra

> Students in a class were asked about the number of brothers and sisters they had. 17 said they had at least one brother. 18 said they had at least one sister. 6 said they had at least one brother AND one sister. 5 said they had no brothers or sisters. What was the least possible number of students in the class?

Well I actually have 2 answers to this question, which both are probably wrong. My first guess is 11, since it is clearly stated in the question that 5 had no siblings and 6 had atleast one brother and one sister.

My second guess is 1, since there has to be atleast a student in the class.

Comment: Well, it *does* say student*s*. Implying that there is more than one.

Comment: Obviously it has to be at least 18 as 18 said something.  Um, I you going to think about *what* they said at all?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It says that there are 18 with at least one sister, and 5 without brothers/sisters. So there have to be at least 23. Now we have to look if something implies that this has to be higher. Because these eighteen said that they had at least one sister, those 17 with at least one brother can all be combined with this, so we get a minimum of 23.

Comment: But how can you get *only* 6 saying they have both.  That means there are 12 who only have sisters and 11 who only have brothers.

Comment: I feel bad.  This is the only answer that is... lower quality, per se, and it gets marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Out of the 17 who had at least one brother, 11 had no sisters.  Combined with the 18 who had at least one sister, this gives us 29 students.  Adding in the 5 who had no brothers or sisters, we get 34.  So there is exactly 34 students.

$$\text{no sister/brother $+$ no sisters some brothers $+$ sisters, with or w/out brothers}=34$$

Comment: Quick and spot on!

Comment: @amWhy Oh, thanks.  :)

Answer (score 2):

There are 4 groups:

$A$ = no siblings

$B$ = only brothers

$C$ = only sisters

$D$ = both brothers and sisters.

$A = 5$.

$D = 6$

$17 = B + D$

$18 = C + D$

So $B = 17 - D =17-6 = 11$.  $C = 18 -D = 18-6 =12$

So there are *exactly* (no "at least" about it) $5+6+11+12 = 34$ students.

5 have no siblings, 11 have only brothers, 12 have only sisters, 6 have both.

So 17 have brothers and maybe or maybe not sisters, and 18 have sisters and maybe or maybe not brothers.

Comment: Sorry to say, @SimpleArt nailed it earlier than you did (in addition to the time you took correcting your answer). Earlier & Simpler.  But nonetheless, good job!

Answer (score 1):

We can also solve it using Venn diagram, make diagram-
[image]

Now, according to diagram,

$B=17-6\;\implies11$

$S=18-6\;\implies12$

$B\&S=6$

$NO=5$

So total number of students-

$B+S+B\&S+NO\;\implies11+12+6+5=34$